# Определить цифры регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

я очень плохо разбираюсь в регулярах, как мне сделать, чтобы он только определял цифры? Если только есть одна буква, то не пропускал!

```
if (!preg_match("/[0-9]/",$g1,$matchs)) 
{ 
$g1 = $matchs[1]; 
echo "ошибка 0"; 
exit(); 
}
```

если к примеру в $g1 = "http1";

он его пропускает а нужно что бы была ошибка фильтрация только цифры!

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: .  

    /^[0-9]+$/

Comment: @ReinRaus алаверды - ваш вариант пропустит такую строку: "12 3 1")

Comment: Нет.  
@big-vl, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @ReinRaus действительно, не пропустит, извините)

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{1,}$
```

Comment: @DreamChild, Пропустит пустую строку, исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ReinRaus спасибо, поправил)

Answer (score 1):

а зачем тут регулярные выражения?..

```
if (($a + 0) eq $a) {...}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/EbnkPO

Comment: может, затем, что ваш код вернет true и для $a = "123" и для $a = "abc" и для $a = "12.3"?

И потом, возможно, регулярки нужны человеку потому что он занимается их изучением

Comment: занятный этот ваш пхп.
@ReinRaus, смотри http://ideone.com/DA6dNW
как написать то же самое на пхп?

Comment: @kolpak, он не наш. Я вообще это ни на каком языке не написал.
Как вариант, смотри http://ideone.com/GgnPiV

Comment: @kolpak, в PHP приведение к целому не только не поможет, но и может создать очень неявный баг  
http://ideone.com/bqDsau  
А к целому надо приводить так:  

    (int) $a;

Comment: @LTKH, Ваш вариант с тем же багом. К целому нельзя приводить в данной ситуации из-за переполнения  
http://ideone.com/PP20Y3  

Comment: @ReinRaus, eq - в перле используется для сравнения строк.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ты приводишь к числу, а я в http://ideone.com/DA6dNW приводил к строке и сравнивал строки

Comment: @ReinRaus, может мы говорим про разные участки кода? Вы имели ввиду преобразование к числу в ($a+0)... так об этом вопрос и не стоял. Просили повторить конструкцию, я ее повторил с теме же багами, почему и написал изначально: "Я вообще это ни на каком языке не написал"...